# syntax error: unexpected end of file .bash_profile

Tags: bash, syntax

I added the below code to empty ~/.bash_profile file and after restarting and login via ssh to the server I get  syntax error: unexpected end of file .bash_profile

```
NODE_ENV=production
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then   . ~/.bashrc fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There needs to be a semicolon or line break before the `fi`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then   . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general tip, I would recommend making code easier to read by using line breaks and indentations wherever possible. For example, you can lay out the lines as below (notice that you don't need a semicolon before fi in this case):

```
NODE_ENV=production
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then   
  . ~/.bashrc 
fi
```

The if and fi line up nicely, making it easy to understand the block of statements between them.

HTH !